# chef solo - vagrant build error

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

Ive been struggling with this for hours and dont seem to be making any progress.  Any tips on where I should start debugging this would be appreciated.

I am attempting to provision a vagrant machine and get the following error.

```
`==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[nginx]"] from JSON
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[nginx]]
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [nginx]
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:08+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: 
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/build-essential/libraries/xcode_command_line_tools.rb
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: 
==> default: NameError
==> default: ---------
==> default: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::LWRPBase
==> default: 
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/build-essential/libraries/xcode_command_line_tools.rb:21
==> default: 
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/build-essential/libraries/xcode_command_line_tools.rb:
==> default: 
==> default:   1:  #
==> default:   2:  # Cookbook Name:: build-essential
==> default:   3:  # Library:: xcode_command_line_tools
==> default:   4:  #
==> default:   5:  # Copyright 2014, Chef Software, Inc.
==> default:   6:  #
==> default:   7:  # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
==> default:   8:  # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
==> default:   9:  # You may obtain a copy of the License at
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:09+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:09+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:09+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-05-14T11:16:09+00:00] FATAL: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::LWRPBase
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.`
```

I am using the berkshelf-vagrant plugin with vagrant

Vagrant 1.6.2

My vagrant file has the following:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

  chef.run_list = [
    "recipe[nginx]"
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Chef. You might want to use [vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) to install a more modern Chef version in your box.

Your issue looks very similar to [COOK-4441](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-4441). Reason: Chef 10, while 11 is required.